# C# Word automation makes Windows Explorer crash

Tags: c#, crash, ms-word, ms-office, windows-explorer

I have written a C# program which import a product list from a .xlsx file and let the user create an order based on that product list.
When the user is finished, the program builds one or more system specifications based on the order.These specifications is written to a .docx file. I have Office 2007 installed on the computer and are using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word namespaces.

The problem:
After I have runned the program, Windows Explorer crashes very often and has to restart. This happens when navigating in folders or when right- clicking on folders etc.
This also happens after the program have been closed and the only solution to make it stop is to restart the computer. It seems like it only happens when I have created the output files (.docx). If i start the program and use it like I normally do, but without creating the word files, the problem don't seem to occur.
After the program have created the output files, Word gets "Visible" to the user for manual editing. The user closes the word application when finished editing the documents.

What can make the Windows Explorer crash when running word automation?
I really need help on this one. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: As a start, check your task manager to see how many instances of WINWORD.exe is running (if any).

Edit: Just see Vinzz answer below, he's getting at the same thing I am, except with a lot more thorough an answer.

Comment: There is no instances of Winword.exe running. The user closes the word application manually after the program is finished. After this, the winword.exe disappears from task manager.

Answer (score 2):

After execution, do you have ghost excel.exe and word.exe processes remaining?

These ghost are likely to make the system unstable.

You're likely not releasing properly the COM objects you instantiated via automation.

Use `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(yourobj);` on each and every COM objects you instantiate. It's a real pain, I know.

Note: be sure that you don't instantiate COM objects without knowing it:

`mySheet = myExcelObject.workbooks[0].Sheet[0]` won't just instantiate a sheet object, but also a workbook object.

**Rule of thumb:** never ever use a secondary property on a COM object ( foo.bar.baz ) and release everything.

**Final note:** don't use [office automation at all](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757) on the server, it's bad, per Microsoft own words, there are fully managed [libraries](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp) for that.

Comment: Should I not see word or excel running in task manager list of processes if there was any "ghosts"? I have tried to release the excel COM objects earlier because i noticed that Excel was still running in task manager. I did not know of "ghosts" until a few days ago, so I am not sure if I have done it right, but there is no Excel running in task manager anymore. Word is closed by user manually, which means I don't have to get rid of "WORD-ghosts".

Comment: Well, a ghost, in this case,is indeed a remaining excel.exe process visib le in the task manager. If you don't have any remaining process, the problem may lie elsewhere. Is your program properly terminated? Are you able to delete the produced .docx? if not, there's still a handle on it from your program.